# why the Power automate flow not writing all rows to the excel file?

Tags: json, python-3.x, excel, power-automate

I have power automate work flow that is reading an API inside `"apply to each 2"`, as seen in the screenshots "`work flow1` and `work flow 2`. Inside the "apply to each 2" there is another loop as `"apply to each 3"`. The purpose of the 2nd loop is to read the body of `HTTP 2` and write the data to an excel file. Below are the in-betweens

There are two parse JSON I had to execute to get the data as per my format. Below are the data format as response from `HTTP2` and two `Parse JSON`

HTTP 2 RESPONSE

```
[
  {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": "[[\"554d3\", \"xyz Ltd\", \"Soft Services\", \"1198325\", \"2023-11-08\", \"2023-12-08\", \"USD\", \"my description\", \"554d3\"]]"
    
     },
     
     
    {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "body": "[[\"9101d\", \"abc Ltd\", \"Spect Ltd\", \"1591\", \"2021-10-04\", \"2021-11-03\", \"USD\", \"my description 2\", \"9101d\"]]"
]
```

Parse JSON RESPONSE --> `same as HTTP 2 response`

Parse JSON 2 RESPONSE

```
{
    "body": [
        [
            "col1",
            "col2",
            "col3",
            "col4",
            "col5",
            "col6",
            "col7",
            "col8",
            "col9"
        ],
        [
            "col1",
            "col2",
            "col3",
            "col4",
            "col5",
            "col6",
            "col7",
            "col8",
            "col9"
        ]
        
        ]
}
```

compose 7 RESPONSE

```
[
    [
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3",
        "col4",
        "col5",
        "col6",
        "col7",
        "col8",
        "col9"
    ],
    [
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3",
        "col4",
        "col5",
        "col6",
        "col7",
        "col8",
        "col9"
    ]
        
]
```

The only difference I see between `Parse JSOn2` and `compose 7` is that the former is list of list, but inside curly brackets, and later is list of list.

They are followed by 9 other compose where I am defining the data with their index value as they appear in the DB. Here when I started the initial mapping I used expression as below

`outputs('Compose_7')?[0]` .. and so on till `outputs('Compose_7')?[8]`, for 9 columns followed by a condition action.

NOTE:

`I have created a Data template excel file format that has two rows with same column names, based on which the data mapping has been done with the DB data. and the name of the data template is report1 and report2` --> `screenshot attached`

condition action: I have to write data to the report1 if `col2 = xyz Ltd` otherwise write data to report2, i.e. `if col2 = abc LTD`

my 1st work flow run failed as the condition was False, i.e `if col2 = xyz Ltd` failed. So, when I looked to the `if no` part, I see below as the input of the "`add a row into table"` action

```
{
  "col1": [
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3",
        "col4",
        "col5",
        "col6",
        "col7",
        "col8",
        "col9"
  ],
  "col2": [
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3",
        "col4",
        "col5",
        "col6",
        "col7",
        "col8",
        "col9"
  ],
  "col3": [
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3",
        "col4",
        "col5",
        "col6",
        "col7",
        "col8",
        "col9"
  ],
  "col4": [
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3",
        "col4",
        "col5",
        "col6",
        "col7",
        "col8",
        "col9"
  ],
  "col5": [
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3",
        "col4",
        "col5",
        "col6",
        "col7",
        "col8",
        "col9"
  ],
  "col6": [
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3",
        "col4",
        "col5",
        "col6",
        "col7",
        "col8",
        "col9"
  ],
  "col7": [
        "col1",
        "col2",
        "col3",
        "col4",
        "col5",
        "col6",
        "col7",
        "col8",
        "col9"
  ],
  "col8": null,
  "col9": null
}
```

and in the response there was an error as show below

```
{
  "status": 400,
  "message": "A value must be provided for item.\r\nclientRequestId: 3e142979-f934-483f-b774-4f670c717073",
  "error": {
    "message": "A value must be provided for item."
  },
  "source": "excelonline-uks.azconn-uks-002.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
```

I also noticed that in all the compose action that I have written to map each column had values for all columns instead of the column's value for which it was intended to, i.e. uuid contained all 9 column's value. As I have mentioned earlier that the expression was as below

```
outputs('Compose_7')?[0] ... outputs('Compose_7')?[8]
```

To troubleshoot further I added another level of indexing as shown below

```
outputs('Compose_7')?[0][0] ... outputs('Compose_7')?[0][8]
```

The above solution did resolve the issue, but writing only data in the excel from 1st iteration. Since I have total 9 rows and out of which 7 are for xyz LTD, and 2 are for abc LTD. So, I believe that there should have been 9 iterations in total, but the `apply to each 3` just ran 2 iterations taking 0th index data of abc LTD and 0th index data of xyz LTD.

I have attached screenshots for each steps that I have explained here. Please have a look and suggest.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

The API that is being called in HTTP 2 has below code

```
import os
import logging
import json
import mysql.connector
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from utils.db_utils import close_connection, execute_query
from utils.utils import get_db_password
from datetime import date

if len(logging.getLogger().handlers) > 0:
    # The Lambda environment pre-configures a handler logging to stderr. If a handler is already configured,
    # `.basicConfig` does not execute. Thus we set the level directly.
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
else:
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


def stored_procedure_call(stored_procedure_name, col_name, entity_field):
    logging.info(f"Fetching DB connection details.")
    try:
        # Load env file
        load_dotenv()
        # Create the connection object
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(
            user=os.getenv('USER_NAME'),
            password=get_db_password(os.getenv('RDS_HOST')),
            host=os.getenv('RDS_HOST'),
            database=os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
            port=os.getenv('PORT'))

        # Create a cursor
        cursor = conn.cursor()
    except Exception as error:
        logging.error("An unexpected error occurred: {}".format(error))

    try:

        # Call the stored procedure with the provided ID
        cursor.callproc(stored_procedure_name, [col_name, entity_field])
        conn.commit()

        result_list = []
        for result in cursor.stored_results():
            rows = result.fetchall()
            for row in rows:
                result_list.append(list(row))
                logging.info(row)
        print("@@@@@@@@@@@@@", result_list)

        if not result_list:
            return {
                'statusCode': 404,
                'body': json.dumps('Stored Procedure Result is not available')
            }

        for item in result_list:
            item[4] = item[4].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            item[5] = item[5].strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

        return {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            'body': json.dumps(result_list)
        }

    except Exception as error:
        logging.error("An unexpected error occurred: {}".format(error))
        return {
            'statusCode': 500,  # Internal Server Error
            'body': json.dumps('An error occurred: {}'.format(str(error)))
        }

    finally:
        close_connection(cursor, conn)


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    '''
    This function is lambda handler function.
    This function connects to DB using environment variables and
    execute a stored procedure.
    '''

    try:
        query_string_parameters = event['queryStringParameters']
        col_name = query_string_parameters.get('tyu')

        call_procedure_1 = stored_procedure_call("Stored procedure", col_name, entity_field1')
        call_procedure_2 = stored_procedure_call("Stored procedure", col_name, 'entity_field2')

        return call_procedure_1, call_procedure_2

    except Exception as exp:
        logging.exception(f"Something is wrong with parameter passing : {exp}")
```

Basically the code is calling same stored procedure where the col_name is dynamic but entity_field is hard coded with two different values.